# Is there an anova procedure that doesn't assume equal variance?

Tags: r, anova, variance, degrees-of-freedom

When conducting a t-test we can always use a Welch approximation of the df, and let go of the assumption of equal variances.

Is there something similar for (even one way) anova?  (any R implementation of that?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest version of [ez](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ez/index.html) lets you pass a `white.adjust` argument to `car::Anova()`, which implements a correction for heteroscedasticity. See `?car::Anova()` for details.

Answer (score 8):

There is a function named `oneway.test()` in the base `stats` package, which implements Welch correction for a one-way ANOVA. Its use is similar to the standard `t.test()` function. It is also referred to as O'Brien transformation (Biometrics 40 (1984), 1079--1087) and might be applied with two or more independent samples.