# Studying independent variable strength with R^2 values

Tags: r, regression, correlation, mixed-model, r-squared

I have a dataframe in R and wish to assess the degree to which each of my independent variables impacts the dependent variable during mixed models analysis. To do so, I've built a mixed model using only 1 independent variable, then added another independent variable and measured the change in the resulting *R<sup>2</sup>* values:

```
library(lme4)

# Use default dataset
df <- sleepstudy

# Create function to measure r^2 values of mixed models
# See: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95054/
r2.corr.mer <- function(m) {
  lmfit <-  lm(model.response(model.frame(m)) ~ fitted(m))
  summary(lmfit)$r.squared
}

# Build the models
m1 = lmer(Reaction ~ (1|Subject), data=df)
m2 = lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1|Subject), data=df)

# Measure the r^2 values
r2.corr.mer(m1)
r2.corr.mer(m2)
```

In this case, I would assess Subject's impact on Reaction to be 0.44 [`r2.corr.mer(m1)`] and would assess Days' impact on Reaction to be 0.28 [`r2.corr.mer(m2) - r2.corr.mer(m1)`]. This second value accords with the *R<sup>2</sup>* value one gets by running `lm(Reaction ~ Days, data=df)`.

My question is: Is it legitimate to measure the degree to which independent variables impact the dependent variable by measuring changes in the *R<sup>2</sup>* value as described above, assuming that there are no interaction terms in the model (i.e. assuming one uses only `+` to join independent variables)? If this is not legitimate, what is the ideal way to measure the degree to which each independent variable accounts for the variance in the dependent variable? I would be grateful for any advice others can offer on this question.